# How to read data from a specific version of Google Sheet?

Tags: java, google-sheets, version, google-sheets-api

I found code examples in internet for reading the data from the latest version of Google Sheet as below:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");
service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getListFeedUrl();
```

But I cannot find any examples, to access a particular version of the Google Sheet and get a cells value in that revision.

Also please let me know, if the above requirement can be completed using google spreadsheet APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not possible:

See: [How to get only recalculated cells from a google spreadsheet via Google spreadsheet API (gdata)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079715/how-to-get-only-recalculated-cells-from-a-google-spreadsheet-via-google-spreadsh)

### Open Issue

There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1388) for this that is now marked "Status: Obsolete".

### Ethercalc

Ether calc, is a google docs style, open source spreadsheet. It should be possible with Ethercalc.

Comment: Checking more on this topic. I will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Suggest you also check google-apps-script. There is a chance they have added this.