# Google Drive Revisions not returning all revisions for a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a script for analyzing changes to a Google Sheets document. When I look at the version history inside of Google Sheets I see what appears to be a complete history of the document going back to 2014. However, when I try to retrieve the history using Google Drive API (which is the only API that seems to support this, it doesn't seem to be supported in Google Sheets API directly?) I only get 226 revisions going back approximately 5 years. I have implemented support for calling iteratively using the getNextPageToken(), and I do get two chunks (one size 200 and one size 26) so I don't think it is related to this. It seems the API really only wants to present in 226 revisions. I get the same result when using Google's API explorer.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70101398

Comment: It seems to be a bug, I also got an incomplete list of `revisionID`. You can [create/file an issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909), as they can explain why revision.list() behaves like this.

Comment: Mr. Rebot: Thanks

Comment: This just bit me as well; were you able to get a resolution to this?

Comment: @Chrest: Unfortunately not - I created an issue in Google's system and other people have "starred" it and written they have the same issue etc. but nothing has happened :(

Comment: The issue is still very much present and it is very annoying.