# How can I grab a range of data from all previous versions of a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, version

I have a spreadsheet that has been updated over the years and would like to grab all of the data from each version from A1:A50 and export that info into a new spreadsheet or log the data from each cell. Is this possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47607375/1595451