# In Google Sheets, is there a way to see when a cell was populated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a spreadsheet that has data added to it sporadically. I'd like to know when data was entered into certain cells.

Is there a way to find the date when a cell was populated?

Note: there are several thousand populated cells, so just looking at past iterations of the entire sheet is not going to work.

Comment: You might be able to determine by comparing to last revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the cell and then select "Show edit history"

Reference

- [View the activity on your Google Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Related

- [GoogleSheets - Is there a way to extract user info from "show edit history" to a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58363986/1595451)
- [Is cell edit history accessible programmatically in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61004713/1595451)

Comment: As of 7/7 this feature seemed to run into an error, then subsequently be removed from the right click context menu.